# What is a 5'-cGMP?

Tags: biochemistry, human-eye

I know in cGMP , there is a bond between phosphate, 5' and 3' C of sugar , but what is 5'-cGMP?

[It is involved in cascade of vision.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 5'-cGMP. That's probably a typo.

In the phototransduction process, there is the breakdown of cGMP to 5'-GMP, catalysed by a Phosphodiesterase:

> PDEs hydrolyze the cyclic phosphate ring that's unique to cAMP and/or cGMP by insertion of a solvent derived hydroxyl at the phosphorous atom in the 6-member cyclic phosphate ring. The product of this reaction is either 5'-AMP or 5'-GMP.

Thus, 5'-GMP is the same of GMP, that is, Guanosine Monophosphate.

(source: [cGMP: Generators, Effectors and Therapeutic Implications](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=C8VyKYkrW1oC&dq=phosphodiesterase%20cgmp&source=gbs_navlinks_s))

Answer (score 1):

As you will see from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_guanosine_monophosphate), you can talk about cGMP, Guanosine cyclic monophosphate  or cyclic 3',5'-GMP. The 3' and 5' indicate the positions bridged by the phosphate in the cylization. Thus, ‘5'-cGMP’ is chemical nonsense.